# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scikitplot'

Tags: scikit-learn, installation

I want to use scikitlearn in my notebook. I installed it by this code:

```
!pip install scikit-plot
from scikitplot.estimators import plot_feature_importances
from scikitplot.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix, plot_roc
```

The installation was correct, but I get the following error when I try to use the packages:

[image]

My lecturer give us a "workspace" via wlan, so I don't work local. Could that be the reason? I would be so thankful, if someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I already tried it with 

`pip install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib` and `pip3 install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib`

Comment: When I use this notebook normal local, then there is no problem. Only when I work in this "workspace". I must work in it becaus local work is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is with the installed versions in the workspace, so yes, the problem is the workspace. Try to uninstall the scikit-learn framework and reinstall it again using only one version of pip to evade version incompatibility. If it does not work, you could try reinstalling all the libraries of the workspace from 0 (or just create a new workspace).

Also, you have another option, and it is to not use the scikit-plot library to do the 3 plots, and use `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot them.

Example of [feature plot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html), [confusion matrix plot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) ,[roc curve plot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda. The code `!pip install scikit-plot` was in my notebook. I cant remember anymore but I think that I installed the package scikit-learn via anaconda prompt with `pip install -U scikit-learn` or `conda install scikit-learn`before I run cells in my notebook. It worked. Maybe I had the old version of anaconda.

Comment: some times conflicts appear when using pip and conda to install different packages, what experts recommend is to install everything with only one package manager.

Comment: what do you mean with package manager? Is that "pip" and "conda"?

Comment: Exactly! https://towardsdatascience.com/which-python-package-manager-should-you-use-d0fd0789a250

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as correct if it helped you !

Answer (score 12):

I removed the "!" and it worked for me. Try

```
pip install scikit-plot
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of '!' you can use '%' like

`%pip install scikit-plot`
will work smoothly with any other packages too

Answer (score 1):

I've had multiple conflicts with the scikit-plot package, given that this project is not maintained since 2018, I moved to a well-maintained package that gives me the same capabilities and support backward compatibility (https://github.com/ploomber/sklearn-evaluation)